# Entitlements.plist versus Appname.Entitlements

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, entitlements

I'm implementing APNS (iOS5, Xcode4) into an application and I'm getting the error:

```
"The executable was signed with invalid entitlements."
```

Research on SO and google is telling me to use Entitlements.plist but I already have Appname.Entitlements, the keys seem to be pretty much identical, and unless I'm missing something adding an Entitlements file is gone from the new file templates.

So What is the difference between these two?  Do I need to just add a plist name "Entitlements"?

Also to verify:

-- My provisioning profile supports APNS.
-- I am using the correct Distribution profile.
-- I'll be doing an Enterprise distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Technical Note TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG31) you should just remove the entitlements file.

> If you are defining a custom Code Signing Entitlements file within your Target > Build Settings, you might try removing that configuration entirely and rebuilding/resubmitting. More often than not, Code Signing Entitlements are defined unnecessarily. You only need to specify a custom Code Signing Entitlements file if your application is utilizing custom keychain access sharing or iCloud. Otherwise, remove the Code Signing Entitlements configuration from all build configurations on your Xcode project's Target > Build Settings, the rebuild and reattempt your submission/validation.

Comment: Its not exactly what I was asking - but it ended up helping me solve my problem.  I removed the Appname.Entitlements, added an Entitlements.plist and everything worked as expected.  Thanks for the help.